# LAN visible to VirtualBox VM with NAT adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nat

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html Virtualbox official documentation shows this quick reference chart for different networking modes and their capabilities.

[image: Network Chart]

It clearly marks that VM to Host communication is not possible with a NAT interface. I understand that to all LAN devices any traffic from the VM appears to come from the Host but was under the impression that with NAT I would have an isolated environment where host is isolated from guest. My guest is on the default 10.0.2.x subnet and my host is on 172.16.0.x I can access any LAN device from my VM. If I recall correctly in the past when I have set up NAT interfaces this has not been the case. There are no iptable rules set in the guest(linux) and nothing in host(windows).

Is this expected behavior? If not any troubleshooting tips for identifying the cause of the issue? Thanks.